# How to calculate the keyspace of a password?

Tags: passwords

Which of the follow keypsaces is the biggest?

option 1: 16 numbers [0,9]
option 2: 30 vowels
option 3: 16 letters from the alphabet
option 4: 32 bits

Can someone help me, by telling me which one it´s the right answer and how we can calculate that? I know that in the last option it´s 2^32, but I´m not sure about the others.

Comment: Consider that you get 2^32 for option 4 from the fact that it represents a keyspace of [0,1] (2 options) chosen 32 times.

Comment: so, in the case of the vowels we have [a,e,i,o,u] (5 options) chosen 30 times, which means 5^30?

Comment: That is correct. Similarly for the other options.

Comment: thank you very much, you really helped me on this one :)

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Consider posting an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Total size of the keyspace is `k^n`, where:

```
k - keyspace for a single character
n - number of characters
```

As such, the total keyspaces for your four options are:

```
1. 10^16
2.  5^30  (~9.3 x 10^20) or 6^30 (~2.2 x 10^23) [if you consider y to be a vowel]
3. 26^16  (~4.4 x 10^22)
4.  2^32  (~4.3 x 10^9)
```